# Is it possible to run fabfile as global script

Tags: python, shell, system, fabric

I wrote a fabfile for our developers this week to help with deployment of DBs and files to remote staging and production environments. Its a fairly complex fabfile that uses configured json file to help set production / staging env variables.

My question is can I somehow add my fabfile to /usr/bin to run the fabfile globally. Being able to run commands without having to copy and past the fabfile into each webroot(design agency problems).

Ideally i could do:

```
fab deploy
```

within Sites/site.dev/ or Sites/site2.dev/ without having to copy the fabfile into those directories. I assume there must be a way to accomplish this using aliases but my knowledge here is too weak to get that job done.

My system is osx.

Comment: Be careful with fab as it is searching for files to run relatively from current directory. If you would write "global script", make sure, you are in proper directory.

Comment: all the commands use relative paths. if i ran fab deploy inside the webroot of my current site it would look for a fabric_config.json file in the current working directory. I have checks to make sure files exist that need to exist before running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved my dilemma. It turns out you can specify fabfile location using the -f flag. from here it was pretty simple to create aliases for commands like

```
alias deployfiles='fab -f ../devops/fabfile.py syncfiles'

$ deployfiles
```

Pretty obvious, surprised no one gave this solution.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, another option is just add the following to the top of your fab file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fab -f

def boo():
    print 'x'
```

Then you can run it like so:

```
(venv)machine:soft kane$ ./test.py -l
Available commands:

    boo
(venv)machine:soft kane$ ./test.py boo
x

Done.
```